# Unable to use os.path.join() kicking out os.chdir() in order to store the downloaded files

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've written a script in python in combination with selenium to download few files from a webpage. I made use of clicks on the links leading to the `.docx` files in order to download them. Once the files are downloaded, they get renamed with some silly prefix. My script can do all this flawlessly.

To store the downloaded files in a folder, I used `os.chdir()` command which I would like to replace with `os.path.join()`. However, this is where I'm stuck and can't find any idea as to how I can use it. Once I can use `os.path.join()` in the right way, I can rename the downloaded files.

***How can I use `os.path.join()` instead of `os.chdir()` in this very situation in order to download and rename files?***

I've written so far:

```
import time
import os
from selenium import webdriver

link = 'https://www.online-convert.com/file-format/doc' 

desk_location = r'C:\Users\WCS\Desktop\file_container'
if not os.path.exists(desk_location):os.mkdir(desk_location)
os.chdir(desk_location) #I wish to kick out this line to replace with os.path.join() somewhere within the script

def download_files(url):
    driver.get(url)
    for item in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a[href$='.doc']")[:2]:
        filename = item.get_attribute("href").split("/")[-1]
        item.click()

        time_to_wait = 10
        time_counter = 0
        try:
            while not os.path.exists(filename):
                time.sleep(1)
                time_counter += 1
                if time_counter > time_to_wait:break
            os.rename(filename,"its_"+filename) #It's a silly renaming in order to check whether this line is working
        except Exception:pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    prefs = {'download.default_directory' : desk_location,
            'profile.default_content_setting_values.automatic_downloads': 1
        }
    chromeOptions.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chromeOptions)
    download_files(link)
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: `os.rename(os.path.join(desk_location, filename), os.path.join(desk_location, "its_"+filename))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the script work using `os.path.join()` instead of `os.chdir()` I needed to change few lines within my script. Thanks @John Gordon for your suggestion in the comment.

Rectified portion:

```
def download_files(url):
    driver.get(url)
    for item in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a[href$='.doc']")[:2]:
        filename = item.get_attribute("href").split("/")[-1]
        #Define the path in the following line in order to resuse later
        file_location = os.path.join(desk_location, filename)
        item.click()

        time_to_wait = 10
        time_counter = 0
        try:
            while not os.path.exists(file_location): #use the file_location here
                time.sleep(1)
                time_counter += 1
                if time_counter > time_to_wait:break
            #Now rename the file once it is downloaded
            os.rename(file_location, os.path.join(desk_location, "its_"+filename))
        except Exception:pass
```